# import node modules in electron angular webpack app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, webpack

I have a electron application using Angular (2) and I pack it using Webpack. I want to use my node modules in my Angular components

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Bonjour} from 'bonjour';
```

**Update**:
I set the target to electron-renderer in my webpack configuration. Now I get the error **error TS2693: 'Bonjour' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here**

Bonjour remains undefined.

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var CommonsChunkPlugin = webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin;

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    target: 'electron-renderer',
    entry: {
        'angular': [
            'rxjs',
            'reflect-metadata',
            '@angular/core',
            '@angular/router',
            '@angular/http'
        ],


  'app': './app/main'
    },

output: {
    path: __dirname + '/build/',
    publicPath: 'build/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].js.map',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
},

resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.html']
},

module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: [/node_modules/]
    }]
},

plugins: [
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'angular', filename: 'angular.js', minChunks: Infinity }),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'common', filename: 'common.js' })
]
};
```

How can I setup my Electron/Angular application in such a way that I can import node modules as mentioned above?

added tsconfig:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "typeRoots": [
    "../node_modules/@types"
]
},
"files": [
    "app/main.ts"
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin in question exported a prototype function in its module.exports. Thus the plugin needed to be instantiated like this:

```
var Bonjour = require('bonjour')
var bonjour = new Bonjour();
```